# Cinnamon crashes when connect to a VNC server on Linux Mint with Cinnamon desktop

Tags: linux-mint, crash, vnc, cinnamon, tightvnc

I installed a VNCServer on Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon. And I want to connect to it via a client on Windows 10 with creating a new Cinnamon desktop. As I know, three different VNCServer can do this, they're VNC4Server, TightVNCServer, and TigervncServer.

### 1.TigerVNCServer doesn't work on Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon.

1) Package tigervncserver cannot be installed because of dependencies peoblem.

2) Package tigervnc-standalone-server can be installed but cannot connect to it.

### 2. VNC4Server and TightVNCServer all work, but get the "cinnamon crash" problem.

When I connect, I get a window that says "Cinnamon just crashed. You are currently running in Fallback Mode. Do you want to restart Cinnamon?". Clicking yes just brings the same prompt up over and over again, while Clicking no can make me use it without desktop background(only pure black).

[Annoying Cinnamon Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj4TA.png)

### 3. There're two kind of xstartup scripts that work with Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon, but both get a different problem.

1) If use this script, it'll create a mate desktop, but no cinnamon, and there's no "cinnamon crash problem". But, fcitx input method doesn't work with it.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS·
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
mate-session &
mate-panel &
```

2) If I uncomment `exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` or do not use any xstartup script, it will create a cinnamon desktop. In fact, this works fine, but always get annoying "cinnamon crash" prompt up when first connect to it. Are there any solutions?